# Custom list flatten OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am currently doing a custom version of `List.flatten` and I blocked at one place.
I currently have:

```
let rec doflatten (ls:int list list) (flatList: int list) : int list =
  match ls with
  | [] -> flatList
  | hd :: tl -> doflatten (List.tl ls) (List.hd hd :: flatList)
```

currently this compiles, but when I call the function, it gives me a "failure hd". It is suppose to do something like:

```
doflatten [[1;2;4]; []; [9]; [5;6]] [] = [1;2;4;9;5;6]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are working with a list of lists, so in this pattern:

```
| hd :: tl -> ...
```

the head `hd` is a list.

However, `hd` can be the empty list. Your code doesn't handle this case properly. You just need to decide what you want to do.

You can have an extra pattern like this:

```
| [] :: tl ->
```

this pattern will match the case in question.